# What's wrong isn't <jsp:expression> equal <%= %> expression in jsp file? & can i use action tags with scriplet in same file?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
```

```
<jsp:text>

    <![CDATA[ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> ]]>
</jsp:text>

<jsp:text>
    <![CDATA[ <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> ]]>
</jsp:text>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>JSP OUTPUT</title>
</head>


<body background="pic_for_try\\Cracked_LCD_Screen_Wallpaper.jpg"
    style="background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: repeat; background-color: #FF8000">

<jsp:expression>request.getParameter("myname")</jsp:expression> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
<%@ page isScriptingEnabled="true|false" isELEnabled="true|false"%>
```

Comment: it's telling me - Undefined attribute name 
  "isELEnabled" and isScriptingEnabled

Comment: Where did you put it? it should be on top.

Comment: Also make you you have the jstl library included

Comment: after  the first line once and the second before html tag